# Coluna data do DataFrame

Tags: datetime, pandas, dataframe

Eu tenho esse DataFrame e gostaria de separar a coluna da data como faço isso?

```
    Data e Hora         Consumo(litros)  Valor Acumulado
0   2017-08-21 20:00:00              65               65
1   2017-08-21 21:00:00              81              146
2   2017-08-21 22:00:00              10              156
```

Comment: O que quer fazer é pegar somente a data da coluna *Data e Hora* ? Ou pegar somente a coluna toda? Já tentou fazer o desejado ? [Edite](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/309354/edit) sua pergunta e coloque o código.

Comment: gostaria de primeiramente separar a coluna data e hora e transformar em duas colunas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Primeiro você deve transformar a coluna `Data e Hora` para [`datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html#pandas-to-datetime)

```python
df['Data e Hora'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Data e Hora'])
```

para criar as colunas, utilizando o método [`dt.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html#pandas-series-dt-strftime) converta o valor da coluna `Data e Hora` para uma string no [formato de data](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior).

```python
# Coluna 'Data'
df['Data'] = df['Data e Hora'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
# Coluna 'Hora'
df['Hora'] = df['Data e Hora'].dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
```

agora tem o resultado:

```
          Data e Hora  Consumo(litros)    ...           Data      Hora
0 2017-08-21 20:00:00               65    ...     2017-08-21  20:00:00
1 2017-08-21 21:00:00               81    ...     2017-08-21  21:00:00
2 2017-08-21 22:00:00               10    ...     2017-08-21  22:00:00
```

Caso queira remover a coluna `Data e Hora` e ordenar as colunas colocando a coluna `Data` e a coluna `Hora` no inicio:

```python
# Remove a coluna 'Data e Hora'
del df['Data e Hora']
# Ordena as colunas
df = df[['Data', 'Hora', 'Consumo(litros)', 'Valor Acumulado']]
```

O resultado agora é:

```
         Data      Hora  Consumo(litros)  Valor Acumulado
0  2017-08-21  20:00:00               65               65
1  2017-08-21  21:00:00               81              146
2  2017-08-21  22:00:00               10              156
```

[Veja funcionando em repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/ShowyLavishBookmarks)

#### O código completo:

```python
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('DataFrame.csv', delimiter=";");

df['Data e Hora'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Data e Hora'])
df['Data'] = df['Data e Hora'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
df['Hora'] = df['Data e Hora'].dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S')

del df['Data e Hora']
df = df[['Data', 'Hora', 'Consumo(litros)', 'Valor Acumulado']]

print(df)
```

#### Referências:

- [pd.to_datetime](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html#pandas-to-datetime)
- [dt.strftime](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html#pandas-series-dt-strftime)
- [Basic date and time types - strftime() and strptime() Behavior](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)